# How to turn a img into a link and have the <a> tag be the height of the image it contains

Tags: html, css

This is the html i have:

```
<a id="test" href="monogram/index.html">
        <img src="img/MonogramApartmentNS.png" alt="The image">
</a>
```

This is the css:

```
#test {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40.0rem;
}

#test img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

The image link works. In css I set the  to display as an inline-block, but the height of the  doesn't match the height of the img. It's 5px higher then the image it contains. How do i get the  to be the exact same height as the image it contains? I need this because I am using borders around the  tag.

A few images:
[image: The height of the image]

[image: The height of the link]

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=white+space+under+image

Comment: i thought it was a problem with the link not the image, never thought of googling under that. Sorry and thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was the image, making the image display: block; should fix it.